# How to insert into MySQL HTML Form data?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I checked a lot of articles and I don't understand it how to insert data into a MySQL table. What is wrong? I guess that my Ajax request is already wrong.

I would be happy to get help!!!

I did not write programs since 20 years. My coding is for sure not good, but I need to get it running.

Any help would be very appreciated!

The code that follows does not `INSERT INTO` and does not `UPDATE`. Why?

Here is the source:

articles.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />

        <title>SoB - Administration</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scroll.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/producttemplate.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js" ></script>

        <style type="text/css">.buttonarea: (\a)</style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          <!--

          var js_string;
          document.getElementById("recordWrite").disabled = true;

          var lastPreviousNext = "";
          var date = new Date();
          var mysqlDateTime;
          var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
          var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
          var dd = date.getDate();
          var hh = date.getHours();
          var min = date.getMinutes();
          var ss = date.getSeconds();

          mysqlDateTime = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + ' ' + hh + ':' + min + ':' + ss;

          //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
          // No submit by onclick
          //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
          elem = document.getElementById('buttonID');
          function stop(e) {
              e.preventDefault(); // browser - don't act!
              e.stopPropagation(); // bubbling - stop
              return false; // added for completeness
          }

          elem.addEventListener('click', stop, false);

          // this handler will work
          elem.addEventListener('click', function() { alert('I still work') }, false);
          //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

        function jsRecordInsertWrite()
        {
            document.getElementById('formheadline').innerHTML = 'Article Database - I save the new item';
            document.getElementById("recordWrite").disabled = true;

            js_articles[0]="";  // set auto increment id to NULL

            // ... the AJAX request is successful
            var updatePage = function (response) {
                alert("insert record successful");
            };
            // ... the AJAX request fail
            var printError = function (req, status, err) {
                alert("insert record failed");
            };
            // Create an object to describe the AJAX request
            var ajaxOptions = {
                url: 'writearticle.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: updatePage,
                error: printError
            };
            // Initiate the request!
            $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
        }

          // -->
        </SCRIPT>

    </head>

    <body class="page page-id-11505 page-template-default" onload="jsRecordCurrent();">

    <div id="page-wrap">

    <?php
    include('includes/header.html');
    ?>

    <div id="container-main">
        <div id="main-content">

            <div class="post" id="post-11505">

                <title>SoB - Administration</title>

                <div class="entry">

                    <form id="form_articles" method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" name="form_articles">

                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">

                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <span style="padding-right:20px">Item</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="Item" name="Item" type="text" maxlength="100" size="25"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <span style="padding-right:20px">Item Category</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="ItemCategory" type="text" maxlength="100" size="25" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr id="buttonarea">

                                <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                    <hr noshade="noshade" />
                                    <input id="recordInsertWrite" type="button" name="recordInsertWrite" value=" Save New Record " onclick="jsRecordInsertWrite()" />

                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </form>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="aside">

        </div>

    </div> <!-- End of main container -->

    </div><!-- END Page Wrap -->

    </body>

    </html>
```

writearticle.php

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('test.test.com:3306', 'admin0', 'star1star1star0');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('sob', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$ID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ID']);
$Item = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Item']);
$ItemCategory = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ItemCategory']);

    if('$ID' == '')
    {
        $sql     = "INSERT into articles values(NULL,'$Item','$ItemCategory')";
        $query  = mysql_query($sql);
            if(!$query)
            {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("error");</script>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("ok");</script>';
            }
    }
    else
    {
        $sql     = "UPDATE articles SET Item='$Item',ItemCategory='$ItemCategory')";
        $query  = mysql_query($sql);
            if(!$query)
            {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("update error");</script>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("update ok");</script>';
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: it does not work. The table does not get updated.

Comment: and the INSERT INTO does not insert the new record.

Comment: Well probably because you arent actually sending any data. But there could be other errors as well. Also you are using jquery so what are you using `addEventListener`? Also you should really do your dates on the PHP side.